# How to update the instances of mapped entity classes using hibernate session methods?

Tags: java, hibernate, transient

I need to update two fields '`from`' and '`to`' of `bp`. `p` is also being fetched along with `bp`. Automatic flushing is disabled, so I have to do flushing explicitly.

```
        Query q = session
                .createQuery(" select distinct bp from BP bp "
                        + " join fetch bp.p "
                        + " where bp.id = 2");

        bp = (BP) q.list().get(0);
        session.getTransaction().commit();

        session = test.services.HibernateUtil
                .getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        bp.setFrom(new Date());
        bp.setTo(new Date());
        session.update(bp);
        session.flush();
        session.getTransaction().commit();
```

When i run the above code it shows following exception:

```
org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: model.P
```

I can't save `p` before flushing as `save()` method tries to insert a new record which violates an `unique key constraint`.

When I try to update `p` before flushing, I got following exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.hibernate.type.LongType.next(LongType.java:79)
    at org.hibernate.engine.Versioning.increment(Versioning.java:131)
```

Is there any way to make the state of `p` persistent?

Comment: Is the `version` column of that object null?

Comment: yes version field of p is null. but that of bp is not null. Thanks

Comment: Hibernate thinks p is transint (i.e. dosn't exist in the database) because its version fild is null. Set it to 0 in the database, and rerun the code.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try transaction commit before flushing the session.

It should work.

Comment: I got the mistake that i did(as pointed out by @Augusto), the version field of p was null, hence p was not getting updated.